# How can I add values to Radio Buttons and calculate answer?

Tags: android, eclipse, radio-button

I have a simpe form with 4 activities containing eight radio buttons. When one activity is answered, it goes to the next, and I want at the fourth activity to show the result of the radio buttons checked. Can somebody help me add values to the radio buttons and calculate the answer?
I want to create a psyhology test, and every radiobutton must have a different value. Adding them up will result in a unique psyhological profile.
Here is one layout and activity from my application.
I am new to this and I appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you!

The layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>


<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/question_1"/>

<RadioGroup 
android:id="@+id/radiogroup"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radiobutton1"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/radio_1"/>

<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radiobutton2"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/radio_2"/>
</RadioGroup>  

</LinearLayout>
```

The activity:

```
package com.example.app_test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      RadioButton buttonOne = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton1);

        buttonOne.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if (isChecked)
                {
                    //Go to the activity for button 1 here
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });

        RadioButton buttonTwo = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton2);

        buttonTwo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if (isChecked)
                {
                    //Go to the activity for button 2 here
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a static variable in every activity and access them in your final activity.this is one way.

Comment: But how can I create a static variable when one button is clicked? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have some options.

1- the easiest is based on using just one activity, 4 linearLayout, one for each question,putting it in a row and changing its visibility . At the end of the fourth, you can sum without problems.

2- another option is to use activities. When the user finish every question group, you have to star a intent to the next activity passing the radio buttons values in a Bundle, if not, you will lost this values, because you can't access others activities values ( you should pass it as a bundle, or save it in a database, sharedPreferences or at storage system...

3 - There is a hibryd between this two solutions, using Fragments, but I recommend you using the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the wrong approach, if you had 20 questions you'd be starting 20 Activities.

You can probably get away with one activity. This should put you on the right path (albeit it is incomplete and naive).

Make a `QuestionActivity`, that has a layout like (pseudo code below):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/answer_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        ...
     </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your `QuestionActivity` you'd have something like:

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {

    private int[] answers = new int[MAX_QUESTIONS];
    private int currentQuestionIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RadioGroup answerGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.answer_group);

        answerGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
            {
                answers[currentQuestionIndex] = checkedId;
                QuestionActivity.this.loadQuestionAtIndex(++currentQuestionIndex);
            }
        });

    private void loadQuestionAtIndex(int index) {
        if (index == MAX_QUESTIONS) {
            computeResults(); // this method would traverse the answers array to tally the results (based on an answer key, or similar)
            return;
         }
        // get the question text from an array resource or some other data source
        // update the question text and radio buttons text
    }
}
```

I hope that gets you going in the right direction. If your questions require interactivity beyond a text (i.e. some questions would show a video), you should consider using the `Fragment` class (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to create reusable pieces of UI and business logic (VideoQuestionFragment, TextQuestionFragment, etc).